# render v-for vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

я вывожу список с помощью v-for, затем когда я удаляю элемент массива по индексу методом splice он удаляется как и ожидалось, но v-for продолжает отображать несуществующей элемент, при этом перестаёт отображать последний элемент массива.

ПОЧЕМУ ТАК ПРОИСХОДИТ ? И КАК ЭТО ИСПРАВИТЬ ?

Родительский компонент:

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="w_max h_max grid grid_center grid_vertical_center">
    <ul class="main">
      <item v-for="(item, index) in tasks" :options="item" :key="index" @delete:item="dell(index)"></item>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import item from '@/components/item'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    item
  },
  data () {
    return {
      list: [
        {
          text: 'text - 1'
        },
        {
          text: 'text - 2'
        },
        {
          text: 'text - 3'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    dell (index) {
      this.list.splice(index, 1)
    }
  },
  computed: {
    tasks () {
      return this.list
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
#app {
  padding: 40px 15px;
  background-color: rgb(250, 242, 242);
}
.main {
  max-width: 940px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 80%;
}
</style>
```

Дочерний компонент:

```
<template>
  <li class="item grid grid_cenrical_center">
    <div class="item__text">
      <h2>{{ item.text }}</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="item__bottom">
      <button @click="dell">dell</button>
    </div>
  </li>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: [
    'options'
  ],
  data () {
    return {
      item: this.options
    }
  },
  methods: {
    dell () {
      this.$emit('delete:item', true)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.item {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: white;
  grid-template-columns: 5fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.item__text {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif
}
</style>
```

[image: img]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в данном коде в том, что вы передали в дочерний компонент данные, а затем попытались их перенести в `data`, а это чревато тем, что пока ваш компонент не пройдет этап пересоздания, вы будете видеть неактуальные данные (хотя на самом деле `this.list` и `task` правильно формируется под действием `splice()`).

**Объяснение** почему так: на этапе создания дочерних компонентов, вы подписываете каждый компонент порядковым номером (исходя из очередности в массиве) - индексируете их порядковым номером (`index`) и когда вы удаляете элемент массива, дочерние компоненты не перерисовываются, а пытаются угодить вашей логике, что приводит к тому, что раз элементов стало на один меньше в массиве, то последнему компоненту нужно уйти (т.к. его индекса уже нет в массиве) и он успешно пропадает с поля зрения.

Таким образом у вас как минимум два варианта лечения данной проблемы, либо поставить условие для перерисовки дочерних компонентов после действий с данными, как вариант (обратите внимание на `v-if` в теге `ul`):

```
<template>
  <ul v-if="item">
    <li class="item grid grid_cenrical_center">
      <div class="item__text">
        <h2>{{ options.text }}</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="item__bottom">
        <button @click="dell">dell</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["options"],
  data() {
    return {
      item: this.options
    };
  },
  methods: {
    dell() {
      this.$emit("delete:item", true);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.item {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: white;
  grid-template-columns: 5fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.item__text {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
</style>
```

либо не использовать данные из `props` в `data` как в этом коде:

```
    <template>
    <ul>
    <li class="item grid grid_cenrical_center">
      <div class="item__text">
        <h2>{{ options.text }}</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="item__bottom">
        <button @click="dell">dell</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
   </template>
     <script>
    export default {
    props: ["options"],
  data() {
    return {
      // item: this.options
    };
  },
  methods: {
    dell() {
      this.$emit("delete:item", true);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.item {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: white;
  grid-template-columns: 5fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.item__text {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
</style>
```

Я привел два варианта оформления **дочернего компонента**.
При подготовке ответа, была использована информация с официальной документации Vue - [Входные параметры (props) во Vue](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)

[Пример для наглядности](https://codesandbox.io/s/red-cache-e5ceo)

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите тут
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State

Вы выбираете для key index, но индекс у массива не изменяется, а изменяется содержимое.

Лучше добавьте к элементам значения id и используйте их в качестве ключа.

Если посмотреть чуть дальше, то https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods

Уберите `key` чтоб не мешать Vue отслеживать содержимое массива.

Answer (score 1):

Не используйте пожалуйста свойство :key вместе с index если собираешься модифицировать массив.

Каждый раз при удалении ты меняешь размер массива и твой список перерисовывается но непредсказуемым для тебя способом.

Свойство :key используется для понимания vue что требуется перерисовать в dom.

И получается следующее, ты удаляешь элемент из массива, размер массива меняется, ключи в виде индексов генерируются с 0 и ты видишь такое поведение.

В документации vue есть об этом упоминание. Ключи должны всегда быть уникальными. Считается хорошей практикой при работе со списками объявлять в объектах id и присваивать его key.